# Custom apache module + Visual Studio 2012 on 64-bit Windows

Tags: apache, module

I have built a custom apache module and got it successfully running in my 64-bit windows machine. However, the same module when I run on another 64-bit machine doesn't work and throws an error in the LoadModule directive, the error being a syntax error, and not being able to find the module.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: You'll probably need to post a lot more information about what's going on, including error messages before you'll be able to get too much help here.

Comment: The error that I see is

httpd: Syntax error on line 130 of D:/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load D:/
Apache2.2/modules/mod_abcd.so into server: The specified module could not
be found.